# Shia rigging the SE system

Tags: discussion, support, sectarianism, shia-sunni

I find very poor quality voting patterns on this site compared to other launched site, and the major cause of this is that most Shia question and  answers are getting voted in favour of Shias even if they are very poor quality. I am very confident that there are 5-6 shia members who are rigging the SE system of Islam.SE in favour of Shiism. I hope the mods have enough tools at their disposal to detect these things.

And is it possible for mods to detect a clique of users who have the same voting patterns on poor quality posts? I guess this would be enough to uncover these users and such an information should be made public.

Comment: This is certainly not a duplicate of that question, it specifically asks about voting patters vs post quality, whereas that post is very broad and the answer given was not implemented. Also that post concerns only with deletion of flagged posts

Comment: Can you provide examples for your claim of Shiite systematic rigging of voting-system so that we can objectively examine them?

Comment: As someone who has been tangentially involved in the cleanup of some amount of vote trickery here, I can assure you that the mods *do* keep tabs on this stuff, @Umar - as described in the linked question and answer.

Comment: @Shog9 so did you find the cases I mentioned in this question? Should'nt such things be made public as a deterrent

Comment: Not gonna embarrass folks publicly, @Umar - those involved were warned and/or deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks, but this behavior is still continuing. A deterrent is needed

Comment: Having one's account deleted doesn't strike you as a sufficient deterrent? Well, there are... other options. If you actually have evidence of this, you can flag the relevant posts for moderator attention or even email me privately (address is in my profile).

Comment: @Shog9 Nice, wikipedia has a similar system  called "meat puppetry " where we can request a check on a list of users who we suspect to be unfair and partisan group. Is this possible to get statistical data on voting patters if we provide a list of users?

Comment: I have some decent tools for this purpose, yeah. I can't reveal the results publicly, but if there's anything to them I'll pass them on to the mod team here and other members of my team and we'll take care of it.